# stacks growing downward and heaps growing upward, what if they encounter?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

This picture could be found on [Operating system concepts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00APSZCEQ), beginning of Chapter 9. The size of virtual address space is **0** to **max**. My question is:

1. what will decide the **max** value? Is it fixed?
2. what will happen if the hole between stack and heap is filled and one of them of both of them want to grow continually?

[image]

I know that my question may be duplicate, but I've read a lot threads and I still cannot get my answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is probably better asked at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: "what will decide the max value?" The maximum of what?

Comment: *What will happen if the hole between stack and heap is filled?* You run out of memory and can't do anything. What would you think would happen? And what *max value* are you asking about? The max at the top of the image? That's the amount of installed memory on the machine (the maximum memory that can be allocated). Again, what else would you expect it to be? *Pick a number between 1 and 10.* *OK. .What's the max I can pick?* Um, 10. It's the max you can pick between 1 and 10.

Comment: @Ken White is 'max' not provided on a per process basis? So there will be multiple of these structures at any time.

Comment: @KenWhite I think that this picture is a virtual address space for one application. And it is virtual memory, not the physical memory.

Comment: @NickA: Yes. My previous comment should have been phrased slightly differently. Change *the amount of installed memory* to *the maximum amount of memory that could be allocated*.

Comment: @sydridgm: That's irrelevant. When the heap and stack meet. you're out of memory. Period. There is no more to allocate. And max still means max, whether it's virtual or physical or a combination of the two - the maximum is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what you are seeing is a very simplified diagram of what happens. First of all all, the underlying hardware sets a maximum logical address range.

Some part of that range will be reserved (either through hardware or software, depending upon the processor) for the operating system. The remaining addresses are for the user address space.

So what you are looking at is a conceptual view of a user address space. This can be further limited by system parameters and process quotas.

> what will decide the max value? Is it fixed?

Thus MAX is a combination of hardware limits, operating system address allocation, system parameters, and process quotas. It can, therefore, be unfixed.

> what will happen if the hole between stack and heap is filled and one of them of both of them want to grow continually?

First of all remember this diagram is only conceptual. One simplification is that the valid addresses within the address space need not be contiguous. There  could be holes. Second, memory layout is usually controlled by the linker. The "text" and the "data" can be reversed or even interleaved.

The blue "hole" will generally be unallocated (invalid) memory pages. Some OS's do not grow the stack. It is preallocated by the linked. In a multi-threaded system, there could be multiple stacks (another simplification of the diagram) and there are often multiple heaps.

As various function map pages into the logical address space, the blue area shrinks. If go goes to zero, the next attempt to map pages will fail.